# what is first, exponential averaging and fft transform?

Tags: signals

I would like to take some processing operations to real time signals recording from the microphone. The operations inculde time weigthing (exponential averaging) and fft transform and some others. The problem is, which is the first and which is the second? Should I apply exponential averaging to the signals, then apply fft transform to the averaged signals, Or should I first apply the fft transform, then apply the exponential averaging to the frequency domain data?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what information you want to extract from the audio or the motive behind your processing the audio.
If you are trying to smooth the signal by removing noise, then you can do the averaging first followed by an FFT of the output of the averaging.
Equivalently, take the FFT of the original signal and apply a lowpass filter in the frequency domain by multiplying the FFT output with some window. Both should give the same result.

FYI. There's no programming involved here. You should ask this on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/.